# More sentences in different languages with AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: xcode, avspeechsynthesizer

My code speaks a text in one language and switches to another language (if necessary).
The Problem is, that only the first Sentence is spoken.
I need a possibility to speak more sentences in more than one language. I need different languages, and this needs a new initialization.
If the first sentence is very short, it sometimes speaks the second one as well. The third is never spoken.
An Suggestions?

```
- (void) StartMyProgramm {
SpeakTextPrefix = @"This is the first Line";
SpeakTextTitle = @"De Titel van het boek is";
SpeakTextSuffix = @"Wie komme ich hier wieder raus";
if (![SpeakTextPrefix isEqual: @""]) {
    [self speakText:SpeakTextPrefix];

} else if (![SpeakTextTitle  isEqual: @""]) {
    [self speakText:SpeakTextTitle];

} else if (![SpeakTextSuffix  isEqual: @""]) {
    [self speakText:SpeakTextSuffix];

}
}
- (void) speakText:(NSString *)textToSpeak {
if (![textToSpeak  isEqual: @""]) {
    //Recognize Language
    NSArray *tagschemes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage, nil];
    NSLinguisticTagger *tagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes:tagschemes options:0];
    [tagger setString:textToSpeak];
    NSString *language = [tagger tagAtIndex:0 scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage tokenRange:NULL sentenceRange:NULL];        
    //Speak
    AVSpeechSynthesisVoice *voice = nil;
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = nil;
    voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:language];
    utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:textToSpeak];
    utterance.voice = voice;
    utterance.rate = 0.3;
    utterance.pitchMultiplier = 0.8;
    [self.synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
}
- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance {
if (![SpeakTextTitle  isEqual: @""]) {
    [self speakText:SpeakTextTitle];
    SpeakTextTitle = @"";
} else if (![SpeakTextSuffix  isEqual: @""]) {
    [self speakText:SpeakTextSuffix];
    SpeakTextSuffix = @"";
} else {
    //do something else
}
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem. The workaround discussed in this question (speak an empty utterance first) worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197952/avspeechsynthesizer-with-ios8

Comment: Tnx, good Idea, I will try this !

Answer (score 1):

Same things happens to me. I guess it is a bug on iOS 8 SDK.

I actually found workaround by setting `preUtteranceDelay` to 0.05 (or more) property of `AVSpeechUtterance`.

Comment: I tried Pre- and PostUtterance Delay already (both with 1.0), didn't help :-)I Hope Apple will fix this Error!